# How to created a admin module to redirect to specific controller when admin user login

Tags: magento2, admin, redirect

```
app/code/Vendor/Redirect/
├── Controller
│   └── Adminhtml
│       └── Login
│           └── Redirect.php
├── etc
│   └── adminhtml
│       └── routes.xml
└── registration.php
```

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Redirect',
    __DIR__
);
```

routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="redirect" frontName="redirect">
            <module name="Vendor_Redirect" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Create the Redirect.php file:
Redirect.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Redirect\Controller\Adminhtml\Login;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Redirect extends Action
{
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath('route/to/controller');
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

I've tried the above module but doesn't work for me, do anyone know what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect the admin user after successful login then you need to create Plugin for this **findfirstavailablemenu()** function

this function is present in this **vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Url.php**

> app/code/Vendor/Redirect/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Backend\Model\Url">
        <plugin name="after_login_redirect" type="Vendor\Redirect\Model\Url" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Redirect/Model/Url.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Redirect\Model;

class Url
{
    public function afterFindFirstAvailableMenu($result)
    {
        return 'route/to/controller'; //set your custom controller path
    }
}
```

**Thanks.**